# How i can setup and using proGrids in unity 2018.1?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i'm a using Unity 2018.1 version and i'm trying to setup proGrids package, after i install it form package manager i get error here is

```
"cannot use because is it not in c# 4.0 language specification"
```

in Editor console log not in visual studio i'm using VS 2019 version by the way, when i changed the scripting runtime form .net 3.5 to 4 than i get a new error here is

```
"packages.unity.com/com.unity.settings-manager@1.0.2/Editor/UserSettingsRepository.cs(61,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SettingsScope' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"
```

So how i can fix this error and can use a progrid safely i need help please . Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remake your project and try again. this usually helps. if it still does not work, either uprade you're version, or uninstall and reinstall your editor.

Comment: I Remake it a many times and i removed the proGrid and install back many times and i did this in a new project didn't work, So what's version you advice me 2019.4 or 2020.1

Answer (score 0):

i recently had this issue, after long days digging then i realize that it should match with your unity version. try updating progrid preview. in my case, i update the progrid 3.0.3 preview 6 ( current ) to 3.0.3 preview 0. and boom it fixed.

Comment: Please read this carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. It will help you to write clear and impactful answers